# Consul Service Mesh send traffic to URL outside the mesh

Tags: haproxy, consul, servicemesh

I'm using Consul to create a service-mesh, it's all working well.

I want to send traffic to an IP/host not managed by the mesh, which doesn't have a side car.

Is this possible, I don't think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consul provides native support for connecting to egress services through proxies called [terminating gateways](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/gateways/terminating-gateway). The destination service only needs to be registered into the service catalog, and the mesh configured to route connections to that service through the gateway.

The [Understand Terminating Gateways](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-mesh-terminating-gateways) tutorial provides a bit more in-depth information on the supported deployment patterns. It also links to a subsequent tutorial, [Connect External Services to Consul With Terminating Gateways](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/terminating-gateways-connect-external-services), which walks through the process of configuring and connecting to external services from within the mesh.